# how to enable playback range in IIS Express

Tags: html5-video, html5-audio, iis-express

It appears that playback range doesn't work in IIS Express:

```
<audio id="demo" src="http://localhost:49581/Media/audio.mp3#t2,4">
```

Is it possible to enable it on IIS Express?  If so, how?

Thanks.

-John

Comment: Your server needs to support byte-range requests. You might find [this article](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/configure-byte-range-request-segment-size-in-application-request-routing) useful.

Comment: The article concerns IIS, but I'm using IIS Express, which doesn't seem to have all the configuration tools that IIS does.  Like almost everything about IIS I've seen, the article is kind of unintelligible to me.